# Uncaught ReferenceError: Define is not defined in Ember/Springboot

Tags: java, spring, ember.js

I know topic sounds duplicate but the problem that I am facing is different than other forums.

I am integrating my ember app with spring web app. I copied the index.html from the `dist` folder of ember to the `src/main/webapp` folder of spring app.

I am getting following error:

> app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ app.js:1

I followed some [instructions I found](https://web.archive.org/web/20180326152814/http://ygrails.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-emberjs/) to integrate the ember app:

> You would have already noticed that ember.js runs on its on server and uses a different port to your spring boot application. The good thing is that, you don’t have to start ember server for using ember.js in your application. There is workaround. The below steps would explain how.
>
> 1. Copy your index.html from “src/main/webapp/dist” folder to “src/main/webapp” folder.
> 2. Open index.html in your editor and update path all css and js files from “assets/xxx.xx” to “dist/assets/xxx.xx”. This is because all your framework related files are bundled in this folders and these are the only files you need.
>
> Now run you Spring Boot application and access localhost:8080 and you would see your ember home page!

**Note:** When I run the ember app separately using ember server, the site is loading properly.

Comment: Have you verified that the `vendor.js` is properly loaded?

Comment: vendor.js is loading properly.

Comment: @ApurvaGupta why you sure about vendor.js ? how did you  check?

Comment: I checked that there is no error on vendor.js load. Should I be looking at something else? and the generated <app-name>.js file has error. I felt it's related to require.js?

Comment: `ember` does use its own [loader](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js). This should be part of the `vendor.js`. Can you post more information? For example outputted HTML and your package.json? Its just not possible to help you with the information you provided.

Comment: Generated Dist folder was not having requirejs dependency. I rebuild app and that helped. Thanks for quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have created an ember app without running ember server with the spring server running only.

**Resources:**

http://ygrails.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-emberjs/#comment-102

[How to configure emberjs routes in SpringMVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699250/how-to-configure-emberjs-routes-in-springmvc/39763383#39763383)

**My Git repo(It's a hello world app with ember app in spring server):**

https://github.com/apurvagupta/spring_app

Hope this will help some people.